# Zend Framework module structure routing

Tags: zend-framework

I have the following structure of my system:

```
application/
   configs/
     application.ini
     router.php
   layouts/
   modules/
      default/
        controllers/
        forms/
        models/
        views/
        Bootstrap.php
      test/
        controllers/
        forms/
        models/
        views/
        Bootstrap.php
    Bootstrap.php
```

**routes.php file:**

```
$useDefaultRoutes = false;

$routes['index'] = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                       '', 
                       array('controller' => 'index',
                       'action' => 'index', 
                       'module' => 'default'));
```

**Main Bootstrap.php file**

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{

    public static function setRoutes(){

        $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance(); 
        $router = $frontController->getRouter();

        $routes = array();


        if(file_exists('../application/configs/routes.php'))
        {

            require_once "configs/routes.php";

            foreach($routes as $routeName => $routeValue){
                $router->addRoute($routeName, $routeValue);
            }

            if($useDefaultRoutes == false)
            {
                $router->removeDefaultRoutes();
            }

        }

    }

    protected function _initFrontModules() {
        $this->bootstrap('frontController');
        $front = $this->getResource('frontController');     
        $this->setRoutes();
    }

}
```

**Problem**

When I type in browser http://address, then default module launches IndexController and 
everything seems to be ok. But if I type http://address/test, then I get error - page not found. If I remove routes.php file, then it works. So what is the problem with my routing ?

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that your complete routes list?

Comment: Remove $useDefaultRoutes = false;

Comment: @ShaunHare Every module has its Bootstrap file. For example test module has its own:

class Test_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{

}

Comment: @Ashley Nothing happens after removing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this new way of routing...

Include this in your `bootstrap.php`

```
protected function _initAutoloadModules()
{
    $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(
        array(
            'namespace' => '',
            'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/default'
        ), 
        array(
            'namespace' => 'Admin',
            'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/test'
        )            
      );
    return $autoloader;
}
```

This is your `application.ini`

```
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
appnamespace = "Default"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "default"
resources.frontController.defaultController = "index"
resources.frontController.defaultAction = "index"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"
resources.layout.layout = "layout"
resources.modules = ""
resources.view[] =
resources.session.remember_me_seconds = 864000
resources.session.use_only_cookies = on
includePaths.models = APPLICATION_PATH "/models/"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
```

and in `module/default/bootstrap.php` add below given variable

```
protected $_moduleName="default";
```

and in `module/test/bootstrap.php` add below given variable

```
protected $_moduleName="test";
```

Comment: This one works ok, but do I have to add every module to autoloader ?

Comment: yes u have to add there only.. with this approach you can even set the master layout in layout folder..

Comment: Is it possible to make it totally dynamic ? Without adding to Autoloader ?

Comment: Ive tried doing   $frontController->addModuleDirectory(APPLICATION_DIR . '/modules/modulename');  With no success.  Adding each module separately as above was only thing worked for me.